# Bash variable piping not working within an alias?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I tried creating the following as an alias in my .bash_profile.

`alias die_memcached_die="ps -ef | awk '/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9"`

It works fine if I run the commands directly on the terminal

`ps -ef | awk '/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

or if I create a bash script to run it.

Just curious why this doesn't work in an alias?

Comment: What's wrong with `pkill -9 memcached`?

Comment: As an aside, `-9` / `SIGKILL` is a particularly unpleasant way to kill a process, which does not give it the opportunity to clean up after itself. Maybe you really need it, but this is just your friendly PSA to say try `SIGTERM` first.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever something doesn't work the way you want with aliases, "use a function instead" is a very good answer. `die_memcached_die() { ps -ef | ... | xargs kill; }`

Comment: ...also, consider the "use pkill instead" suggestion seconded. Also, you should really consider using SIGTERM first -- if you're using a good process supervision system, many of those will automate the process of using a SIGTERM, waiting a configurable timeout, and then using SIGKILL only if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on pkill; wasn't aware of that one.  As far as the -9; I know this isn't the "nice" way to kill a process.  I use die_ in my aliases to indicate I'm using a -9 or a surr_ or surrender_ if I want to let the process cleanup. This is also not something I'm rolling out to a production server, but rather just convenience aliasing I use locally to save myself some typing during a long day of development :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you wrap your alias definition in double quotes and so the shell immediately expands `$2` and your awk script isn't what you expect it to be.

```
$ cat aa
alias die_memcached_die="ps -ef | awk '/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9"

echo 'Alias command run is:'
echo 'alias die_memcached_die="ps -ef | awk '\''/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'\'' | xargs kill -9"'
echo 'Alias actually is:'
alias die_memcached_die

alias die_memcached_die='ps -ef | awk '\''/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'\'' | xargs kill -9'

echo 'Alias actually is:'
alias die_memcached_die

$ /bin/bash aa
Alias command run is:
alias die_memcached_die="ps -ef | awk '/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
Alias actually is:
alias die_memcached_die='ps -ef | awk '\''/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print }'\'' | xargs kill -9'
Alias actually is:
alias die_memcached_die='ps -ef | awk '\''/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'\'' | xargs kill -9'
```

That being said both of the comments on the OP about this being a poor alias and a poor idea are correct.

Comment: Thanks; I switched to pkill since I wasn't familiar with it and it's shorter, but this works and answers my question as it was stated.

Answer (score 4):

Alias should be enclosed in single quotes to prevent the shell from interpolating variables that are preceded by `$`.

You should have your alias like:

```
alias die_memcached_die='ps -ef | awk "/memcached/ && !/awk/ {print \$2}" | xargs kill -9'
```

You can have `awk` definition inside single quotes but then you need to make sure you escape them.

Also, have a look at functions too. They provide better scalability and reliability over aliases.